# Creating Mock Auth Object in CakePHP Controller Test

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

Just begun creating some unit tests for my controllers within my CakePHP application however I am completely flummoxed on how I should create a mock for the Auth Component, I have read the CookBook and thought I had it right, but keep getting thrown this error.

```
Error: Call to a member function allow() on a non-object
```

Within the controller I am testing there is a beforeFilter function with the following code:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('create');
}
```

Within my test I have included the following:

```
$Leagues = $this->generate('Leagues', array(
    'components' => array(
        'Auth'
    )
));
```

I have played around with `staticExpects()` also but it doesn't seem to have much affect (I am also unsure what I need to put in to `staticExpects()`).

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by mock? Just stuffing an object with data that you set? The error you're getting is because you need to use

`$this->Auth->allow(array('create'))`

Comment: In regards to what I am talking about: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html#using-mocks-with-testaction - I have tried what you have suggested and that does not work either and doesn't match what is suggested in the Cook Book in regards to Auth->allow http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#making-actions-public

Comment: If I use your code I get the following error: 'Indirect modification of overloaded property Mock_LeaguesController_173b7f97::$Auth has no effect'

Comment: I updated my response. Try that. I have always used my original answer, but it appears there is more than 1 way to do it. For that matter, what version of Cake are you using?

Comment: Using 2.4.4 I am not having an issue with Auth allow working, every version I have tried works for the actual application but when I am trying to test the controller I am having issues mocking the authentication object.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue - I have included the Auth component within AppController.php, and not specifically within the controller I was trying to test. By including it with my controller specifically the errors have gone away.

Comment: won't accept this as the answer unless someone comes back with a different solution which doesn't mean I need to reinclude the components.